# Jenkins calling groovy script security errors

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

I'm currently working on running bentolor's [idea-cli-inspector](https://github.com/bentolor/idea-cli-inspector) in my pipeline for static analysis. Unfortunately, I cannot find any documentation on how to allow parameters using the "load" command, and this command works by bringing in source anyway, so I made my own function, but unfortunately, it isn't quite working out (probably due to script security).

Function:

```
def callIdeaInspector() {
    String[] args = ['-i', '/Applications/Android\\ Studio.app/', '-p', '.idea/inspectionProfiles/CompanyName.xml', '-d',
        'src/main/java/com/CompanyName/', '-l', 'ERROR']
    Binding context = new Binding(args)
    result = new GroovyShell(context).evaluate(new File("../btMobileApp/ideainspect.groovy"))
}
```

Error:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: unclassified new groovy.lang.Binding java.util.ArrayList
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `@NonCPS` to your function?

Comment: What does noncps do?

Comment: So, I decided to implement the idea-cli-inspector using a config file instead, so now I have a new issue described here: [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37392343/why-wont-groovy-run-in-jenkins-pipeline)

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Manage Jenkins → In-process Script Approval* and approve all requests there. Re-run the script and repeat the process if needed.

Comment: the `new` doesn't appear there.