# Why won't groovy run in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

I am currently trying to run a groovy script from my pipeline as one of my nodes, but I ran into this error:

```
[CompanyName] Running shell script
+ ./ideainspect.groovy
env: groovy: No such file or directory
```

Also, I tried installing the plugin for groovy, but for some reason, it won't install. Whenever I refresh the page for tools, the installer goes away. Am I installing groovy wrong? Please help!

Edit: Relevant Data

```
stage 'Static Analysis'
node {
    dir("Android/btMobileApp") {
        sh "./ideainspect.groovy"
        sh "./gradlew checkstyle lintDebug"
    }
}
```

And the ideainspect.groovy file is an executable with the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env groovy`, which could be the problem.

Comment: what does the relevant part of your jenkinsfile look like?

Comment: Added the information above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your jenkins user have groovy on its path? If so ditch the shebang and try

sh 'groovy ideainspect.groovy'

If it's not on the path, you can try

sh '/usr/bin/groovy ideainspect.groovy'

(or wherever groovy is installed)

Or alternatively add it to the path environment variable using Manage Jenkins -> Configure Systems. This may not be appropriate if you have lots of projects using different versions of groovy

Comment: Is there a way to test if it is installed on the path? I have installed it on the machine, I just can't tell if the user has access.

Comment: Just try the sh 'groovy ideainspect.groovy'. If it says something like 'cannot find groovy' then it's not on the path. Or ssh onto the box and su to the jenkins user, then try and run groovy from there, amounts to the same thing.

Comment: Ok, using the first method from the script console in manage jenkins, I get the error: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.sh() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [groovy ideainspector.groovy]
Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), run(), run(), any(), each(groovy.lang.Closure)

Comment: If I su into the jenkins user and run 'groovy -h' I do get the help screen though...

Comment: Are you sure you have quoted that command correctly? looks like it is passing 2 arguments to sh in an array, rather than the one argument  'groovy ideainspect.groovy'

Comment: If that doesn't help https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples/blob/master/docs/BEST_PRACTICES.md has a section on groovy gotchas.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112704/discussion-between-twosided-and-mark-chorley).

Comment: For those who would like to know what happened, we deduced that I had not set correct permissions to the folder where groovy was located, so jenkins couldn't find it. All fixed now thanks to this awesome guy!