# Contract Checking in Maven Build

Tags: java, maven, jetbrains-ide, contract, openjml

I'm working on a Java codebase in IJ and currently building with Maven. I would like to supplement some of the code with some form of contracts *that will get picked up in the Maven build*. So far, I've been unsuccessful in my search for such a capability off the shelf:

- [OpenJML](http://www.openjml.org/), but that seems to require its own tool to analyse your code and I couldn't find a way to integrate it easily into the build.
- [Jetbrains Contracts](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/contract-annotations.html). These will raise a warning in IntelliJ via an inspection, but they don't affect the build.

**Note:** I only care about compile-time-checkable contracts here. I have JUnit to throw at the Runtime side of things.

**Contracts to Enforce:**

I've added this section to answer the comment asking what kind of contracts I'd like to enforce. Ideally, I'd like the most powerful solution possible conditional on that solution being *complete*. When I say complete here I mean a language of contracts & a contract checker such that every statement in the language can be checked as good/bad by the checker at compile time. I'm aware this may be a big ask, but I'd be happy with even the simplest of contracts e.g. [those offered by Jetbrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/contract-annotations.html).

For a concrete example, consider this function:

```
public static Long safeToLong(String value) {
    if (value == null) {
      return null;
    }
    try {
      return Long.parseLong(value);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

This successfully passes the Jetbrains contract:

```
@Contract("null -> null")
```

And fails this contrived contract:

```
@Contract("null -> !null")
```

But with the above, contrived, bad contract, the Maven build still works just fine. The build doesn't pick up the inspection results- these are only visible from within IJ. I'd like to be able to hook into the build and fail if any contracts are violated.

Comment: Could you give examples of contracts you want to enforce?

Comment: @JFMeier I've updated the question

Comment: Have you looked through the list in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract ?

Comment: @JFMeier no I haven't actually. I was really just looking for a quick pointer from someone else who might have set this up practically. I'm sure if I spent enough time I could work something out from scratch, but I was trying to avoid reinventing the wheel. It's more the hook into the Maven build, rather than the contracts themselves, that I'm interested in. Thanks for the link anyway.

Comment: It would be interesting to know if a framework like that exists, but unfortunately, I never heard of a sophisticated tool like this.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to dig into it myself. I'll post any findings here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, that works for IntelliJ Contracts. It's a bit messy, but it works:

- Download/clone [Bentolor's CLI inspector](https://github.com/bentolor/idea-cli-inspector) tool into your working directory i.e the directory where the .idea folder is
- [Create an IJ inspection profile](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203928790-Inspection-profiles) with just these inspections enabled: **Constant conditions and exceptions** and **Contract Issues**
- [Create an inspection scope](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.3/scopes.html) if you like - this will restrict your inspections to run only on certain files
- Edit that .ideainspect file that comes with Bentolor's tool, setting your inspection profile & scope that you've just defined, or use project defaults if you haven't defined any
- Also in the .ideainspect file, set the **ideahome** property to the path where you've insalled IJ e.g. ideahome= C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.6
- Finally, to include this in the Maven build, add the following to your POM.xml:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>verify</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>execute</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <properties>
      </properties>
      <scripts>
        <script>file:///${project.basedir}/idea-cli-inspector/ideainspectMvn.groovy</script>
      </scripts>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <!-- any version of Groovy \>= 1.5.0 should work here -->
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugin>
```

### Troubleshooting

If you get [this EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-152045) while running the inspections, you may be able to fix it by adding -Dswing.noxp=true to the end of the file bin\idea64.exe.vmoptions where IJ is installed- the fix is documented at the end of this [IJ crash thread](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000094364-IntelliJ-crashes-as-soon-as-it-opens-last-project).

### Gradle Variant

To add this to your Gradle build it's simpler than in the Maven case. Just add this task to your build.gradle file:

```
task inspect(type:Exec) {
  workingDir '/idea-cli-inspector'

  //on windows:
  commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'groovy ideainspect.groovy'
}
```

Comment: Related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37348453/jenkins-calling-groovy-script-security-errors and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37392343/why-wont-groovy-run-in-jenkins-pipeline.